# MarkLogic I don't know how to get all the result

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Hello I am trying to read a module with this code:

```
(: Entry point - must be a read-only query. :)
xdmp:invoke(
'/path/mydocument.xqy',
(xs:QName('var1'), 'test',
xs:QName('var2'), "response"))
```

I am new in MarkLogic, I am using groovy and the api to connect to it, but also I saw I can invoke the module with this and indeed I did but it returns me

```
your query returned an empty sequence
```

I want to know if I can query `xs:QName('var1'), 'test'`, changing test with a wildcard or how can I get all the information from the file called `/path/mydocument.xqy`?

I tried to use this:

```
xdmp:document-get("/path/mydocument.xqy)
```

but it says the file is not found. Although, if I use invoke I can query it, but I don't know what are the values I have to pass. I was wondering if there is something like sql using %% or something to give me all the data.

Comment: YOu have soooo many layers here, it is difficult to see  where and how to help you.  I suggest you first show a sample document and the code within your main module that you are trying to invoke. Then clearly state the expected outcome.

Comment: Are you attempting to read the module, or execute it? Can you post the code from your `/path/mydocument.xqy` and describe what your expected output would be?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the first question: "I am trying to read a module "

- IF the module is in the database, then you must query the Modules database in which the module resides.
- If the module is in the filesystem then you cannot directly access its source as a document but you can by executing [`xdmp:filesystem-file()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:filesystem-file)

Simplification:

With the Default configuration of the server and REST client,  user placed modules are in the "Modules" database and user placed documents are in the "Documents" database. This means, if you do a GET (read a "Document") with no additional parameters, it will return documents from the "Documents" database.  Assuming you are using the default configuration for client and server, this would result in the behavior you are seeing.  E.g. your Module code is in the Modules database, doing a GET for it by name will search the Documents database and correctly not find it.

You don't mention, and I don't know, the groovy library being used, but the REST API itself and all implementations of general purpose ML REST client libraries I am familiar with have options for overriding the default database with another.  If the groovy library supports that, then specify the "Modules" database for your query and it should return the module document. Note: `content-type` will be `application/text` not `text/xml`.

You can simplify things for testing by bypassing the libraries and simply use a browser and try a URL like this  http://yourserver.com:8000/v1/documents?uri=/your/module.xqy&database=Modules

Ref: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents

Making the appropriate changes to the path and server for your use.

If you are still confused, then you should start with the basic MarkLogic tutorials and work through them one by one. You will most likely succeed faster by doing this then jumping straight into coding you don't understand yet.

DETAIL:

Note:  The default behaviour is to EXECUTE documents when doing a GET call, using the Modules database.  Thus doing a   GET of http://yourserver:8000/your/module.xqy will EXECUTE it not return its source.

You will notice the REST API has a uri query parameter. This is EXECUTING the REST API code on /v1/documents which in turn will read the document specified by the uri and database parameters and return it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can use:

```
xdmp:invoke(/pview/get-pview-browse-profiles.xqy,
cts:and-query((
  cts:element-value-query(
    xs:QName("letter"),"*", "wildcarded"),
  cts:element-value-query(
    xs:QName("collection"),"*", "wildcarded"))))
```

although it doesn't return anything

Comment: Absolutely not (since the vars must be a sequence of even number values as name value pair.  But I will not expand on the issues here as answering your own post with a second post is just really confusing, Refine your original post rather than add more responses to your own post